# How to inject a default version of an object in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a bunch of groups that someone can be members of.  I would like to assign a default group in spring which I can autowire and use in the event that someone is not a member of any other group.

The default group would be a Group object, the same methods and api etc, it's just one that has the default values.  It would have to be built at configuration.  I want to make it injectable because the logic that needs the default group is in a general project, while the default group would be built in a project that uses the firsts jar, ie the logic that needs the default group is not aware of the methods used to generate it.

How can I build something during the configuration phase of spring and inject it?

Comment: If it is feasible to change target source code, target class where you need default Group, can simply implement "InitializingBean" interface and use "afterPropertiesSet(...)" callback method to add default group on some conditions such as if (groups.isEmpty()) { addDefaultOne() }.

Comment: Another way can be to create BeanFactory for specific bean (target bean who needs default value on some conditions), and create it using conditions like "if (groups.isEmpty()) { addDefaultGroup(..) }". This approach doesn't require to change target's source code and also works transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally follow what you're saying. But if you have multiple implementations of some `Group` interface which you want to inject under different circumstances I'd recommend the the use of `@Profile`.

You'd just need to work out how to activate the correct profile for your use case.